# ngIf for iterating through two different Arrays

Tags: angularjs, angular-ng-if

I have this piece of code:

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in someController.searchResults" 
    ng-class="{'selected': tableRow.selected}" 
    ng-click="selectRow(tableRow)" >
```

In this piece of code I'm iterating through `searchResults` array.

I need to add a condition (want to do it with **ngIf**).

- If the condition is **true** I'll iterate through `someController.searchResults`
- If condition is **false** I want to iterate through another Array  e.g: `someController.someOtherSearchResults`

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use plain javascript in the `ng-repeat` attribute, like so:

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in (someController.importantBoolean ? someController.searchResults : someController.someOtherSearchResults)" 
        ng-class="{'selected': row.selected}" 
        ng-click="selectRow(row)" >
</tr>
```

See the following plunker for an example: https://plnkr.co/edit/Nxh9gVB9GDP5FaLVDGrS

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<div ng-if="Your condition(True)"> <tr ng-repeat="row in 
someController.searchResults" 
ng-class="{'selected': tableRow.selected}" 
ng-click="selectRow(tableRow)" >
```

```
<div ng-if="Your condition(False)"> <tr ng-repeat="row in 
someController.someOtherSearchResults" 
ng-class="{'selected': tableRow.selected}" 
ng-click="selectRow(tableRow)" >
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Please filter the data before passing the data to view.

```
if(condition){
    this.results=searchResults;
    else{
    this.results=someOtherSearchResults;
    }
```

And in template keep it simple:

```
   <tr ng-repeat="row in someController.results" 
        ng-class="{'selected': tableRow.selected}" 
        ng-click="selectRow(tableRow)" >
```

OR

```
<tr ng-if="condition" ng-repeat="row in 
someController.searchResults" 
ng-class="{'selected': tableRow.selected}" 
ng-click="selectRow(tableRow)" >

<tr ng-if="!condition" ng-repeat="row in 
someController.someOtherSearchResults" 
ng-class="{'selected': tableRow.selected}" 
ng-click="selectRow(tableRow)" >
```